# Keno Grid with Angular Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I just started working with the Kendo Grid, and so far I hate it.  I find simple tasks difficult, and getting help even harder.  Currently, I have a grid with a button that runs a method that changes the data in my SQL database.  However, I can't get the grid to refresh after the procedure completes.  I have to press F5 in the browser in order to see the changes.  Here is my controller code:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {

        dataSource: {
            transport:{
                read:{
                    url:'/SSQV4/SSQV5/Search/GetBusinessUnits',
                    type: "GET"
                }
            },
            sort: {field: "intOrder", dir:"asc"}
        },
        batch: false,
        reorderable: true,
        sortable: false,
        editable: "inline",


        columns: [
          { template: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="MoveUp(#=OperatorBusinessUnitID#)"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" style="cursor:pointer"></i>', title: "List Order" },
          { field: "intOrder"},
          { field: "OperatorBusinessUnitID", title: "Business Unit ID" },
          { field: "vchDescription", title: "Business Unit Name" },
          { field: "vchOperatorSystemID", title: "Operator System ID"},
          {
              command: [
                { name: "edit", text: " " },
                { name: "destroy", text: " " },
              ], title: "Action"
          }
        ]



    };



   $scope.MoveUp = function (id) {
        operatorService.moveup(id)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.businessUnits = data;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.grid.dataSource.read();
            }, 7000)
        });
    };
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="OperatorCtrl ">
    <kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-scope-field="grid">

    </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, PLEASE help.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where's your function that sends the updated data to your server? I don't see it.

Comment: its at the bottom its called $scope.MoveUp

Comment: How does that update the data on your server? All you do is pass it an `id`. If I change the `vchDescription`, how does your server get that information?

Comment: There is a field in the table called intOrder that changes the sort order  it uses the id to know which record to change.  That logic is handled by the SQL stored procedure.  It doesn't handle edits to other fields.  The data comes back correctly.  But the grid won't refresh to show it unless I press F5.

Comment: Why are you using `$timeout()`? Is `operatorService.moveup()` not a promise?

Comment: because the example sent to me by Telerik Support Team used timeout.  It didn't work with or without timeout.

Comment: I don't mean to sound crass, but you do realize that the read doesn't occur until 7 seconds after you call `operatorService.moveup()` because of using that `$timeout()`? That's an eternity in web apps. Have you debugged this?

Comment: It didn't work without the timeout either.  And of course, I have debugged it.  It doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95070/discussion-between-brett-and-rani-radcliff).